# Async/Await for LINQ methods

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I've spent the whole day today reading about async/await but I still can't completely get my head around it. I understand that within an async method when the await statement is called - the method is paused until a result is returned. I want to improve performance within my Web Form for inserting data into my database. Basically, currently I'm doing this:

```
Protected Async Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim task as Task = CreateItem()
    ClearModalControls()
    CloseModal()
    await task
End Sub

Private Async Function CreateItem() as Task
    Dim item as Item = New Item With {
        .id = 1,
        .name = "task"}
    _db.Items.InsertOnSubmit(item)
    _db.SubmitChanges()
    Grid.Rebind()
End Sub
```

I'm trying to close a modal (which has I/O controls for user input) before the Item object gets inserted in to the database as it takes a couple of seconds to do so. In those couple of seconds - the user could be navigating the website and/or doing any other action. It seems that I cannot get my desired functionality. Are there any issues with my code?

I'm aware that I could just have `await task` at the end and remove `Dim task as Task = CreateItem()` but I have some logic in that method in case of errors and whatnot that would prevent the Modal from closing/pull up the modal again if it is closed.

EDIT: My Modal/Controls are AJAXified. The postback does not reload the page, only the panel.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. For web forms the advantage of async/await is threads are not locked up on I/O operations and can server **other** requests. It does not mean the response of a button click on a web form is returned to the client/browser any faster than when you are not using async/await. So the user (with a traditional web form post / callback) still has to wait the same amount of time for the response to return.

Comment: You could introduce AJAX into your web form and use something like JQuery's `$.ajax` call to submit data to the web server using JavaScript. This would leave the browser more responsive and would require less work to rebuild the entire web page after POST and less overhead of sending the entire HTML form/frame back to the client when its done.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the fact that I've AJAXified most of my page.

Comment: There are no asynchronous calls in that snippet. `SubmitChanges` is a *synchronous* call. `async` doesn't make a method asynchronous automagically, it allows you to *await* for a real asynchronous method to complete. You should use `SubmitChangesAsync`, return the task without awaiting it an rebind *outside* the method, afer the `await CreateItem()` call.

Comment: Async/await on the server side has nothing to do with preventing users from doing unrelated actions while they are waiting for a button to respond. If you want to close an HTML dialog before an ajax call returns, do so by calling `close` right after `$.ajax` as opposed to a `close` in a `done` handler. But then you will have to redisplay the window if the call fails.

Comment: Can you expand your answer? I'm not quite sure what you mean. A short simple code snippet would be of great help.

Comment: Set `Option Strict` to `On` and your code will not compile. That will help you to get feedback faster

Comment: @GSerg so, basically, if I use ajax to close the modal and the rebind the grid when the insert is finished, do I even need async/await at all?

Comment: Ajax on the client side and async/await on the server side are completely unrelated. You want async/await on the server side to achieve [what Igor said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621074/async-await-for-linq-methods?noredirect=1#comment66548207_39621074) - free up some threads on the server so that it can accept more calls per second. If you don't need to achieve that, it's irrelevant if you are using async/await, it's your personal choice.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Just trying to get my head around it.